# Trigger to update Primary field as false

Tags: apex

I am writing a trigger on `Customer__c` object to update checkbox field `Primary__c=FALSE` in Customer object if Parent Account has already a customer record with `Primary=true`. I am getting error as

> System.FinalException: Record is read-only'

at last line of below trigger - `con.Primary__c=FALSE;`.

please help.

```
Trigger PrimaryCustomerValidate on Customer__c (after insert, after update)
{
    Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<id>();
    Map<Id, List<Customer__c>> accountIdContactMap = new Map<Id, List<Customer__c>>();
    Account acc = new Account ();    
    for(Customer__c con:Trigger.New)
    {
        accountIdSet.add(con.Account__c); 
    }
    for(Customer__c con:[SELECT Id, Primary__c, Account__c FROM Customer__c WHERE Account__c =:accountIdSet AND Primary__c = TRUE])
    {
        if(accountIdContactMap.containsKey(con.Account__c))
        {
            accountIdContactMap.get(con.Account__c).add(con); //Here we are adding Map accountIdContactMap with Account.Contacts 
        }
        else
        {
            accountIdContactMap.put(con.Account__c, new List<Customer__c>());
            accountIdContactMap.get(con.Account__c).add(con);
        }
    }

    for(Customer__c con:Trigger.New)
    {
        if((accountIdContactMap.containsKey(con.Account__c))&&(con.Account__c!=NULL)&&(con.Primary__c==TRUE))
        { 
            if(accountIdContactMap.get(con.Account__c).size()>1)
            {
                con.Primary__c=FALSE;
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only modify the object for which a trigger is called during the "before" phase. Your trigger is written for "after" phase where these objects become read-only.

The simplest solution is to change the processing to the "before" phase, if that is possible.

Something else you should consider:

The trigger can be called for multiple Customer__c instances (up to 200 at a time). When you are looking to see if you have too many existing Customer__c instances for a given Account that have Primary__c set, you need to consider the input Customers as well as any others already in the database otherwise your trigger may misbehave (e.g. you have a Customer set primary. You modify that Customer again in some way and the trigger sees that the account for the Customer already has a primary and will set this Customer primary = false when it should not (because the primary IS this Customer).

You also need to consider governor limits - if you have a lot of Customers for the various accounts referenced by the Customers passed to the trigger you could accidentally query too much data and get a runtime error